# Parse.com - New Dashboard - Not able to import data and sort columns

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using the new interface of Parse Browser. It looks beautiful and seems very useful. But I experience a couple of troubles.

- I can't import data into
- I can't sort columns

Somebody can help me? or where can I report these issues?

Answer (score 3):

Well,

After more than 2 hours I have come to the conclusion that in this new version of the DashBoard/DataBrowser it's not possible sort columns or import data...
I don't know if it will be implemented in the future.

I will continue in the old version for the moment,

**URL old DashBoard**

- https://www.parse.com/apps/-ProjectName-

**URL new DashBoard**

- https://dashboard.parse.com/apps/-ProjectName-

Comment: Any updates on this? The open source version of Parse Dashboard is also missing an import from CSV/JSON feature.

Comment: Hi @gregyoung14, I don't know how you can import a CSV/JSON file in your OpenSource version of Parse, but take al look at [BackendLess](https://backendless.com). I have two projects in Parse.com and I'm going to move them into **BackendLess**